# 1 liter of hard Apple cider left

Tags: cider, secondary-fermentation

So after activity had died down in the airlock, I've transferred into the secondary carboy and I've got just about 1 liter left over. Any suggestions?

I have a couple of plastic bottles, but I'm concerned with them being sealed (screw top lid) as I can see that there is still a reaction going on.

All advice welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your primary, and put everything back in that carboy for secondary. At the risk of transfer exposure to O2, but can be done easily to avoid it.

Or put an airlock on the 2 liter bottle and let it ferment separate from the rest. This would minimize transfer O2 exposure.

Or leave them sealed in a 2 liter soda bottle, this will naturally carbonate them. With a gravity of 1.010 going into secondary it should be fine. When they are rock hard, let out some pressure to relieve it.

Comment: I got it done pretty quickly. What effects can oxygen have on it? How long can it be exposed?

Comment: @CiderMonkey o2 exposure oxidizes the cider once alcohol is in it. Bad oxidation will make it taste stale, old or a flavor like paper or cardboard. But it really only happens if you splash it, if you use tubes to fill from bottom up, the head space does little to oxidize.

Comment: Thanks evil. I don't know how to close this thread as answered. 